# Integration of this weird integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Okay so I've racked my brains through and I've not been able to progress.I need to integrate this expression

$$\int{ \frac{dx}{5 \cos x-12 \sin x}}$$
Guys any hint would be a life saver!! Thanks in anticipation.

Could there be anything with making a triangle and finding respective trigonometric ratios from there?

Answer (score 3):

Use $\sin(x)=2t/(1+t^2)$ and $\cos(x)=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ where $t=\tan(x/2)$.

Then $dx=2 dt/(1+t^2)$ and
$$\int{ \frac{dx}{5\cos x-12\sin x} }=\int{ \frac{2dt}{5(1-t^2)-12(2t)} }=\\=-2\int{ \frac{dt}{(t+5)(5t-1)} }
=\frac{1}{13}\int{ \frac{dt}{t+5} }-\frac{1}{13}\int{ \frac{5dt}{5t-1} }
\\=\frac{\ln|t+5|}{13}-\frac{\ln|5t-1|}{13}+C.$$

Comment: Man that is some answer!!! But how did you think it out? Please tell me the logic.Oh and an upvote for you

Comment: This is a standard substititution when you have to integrate a rational function of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: @Zlatan See also here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Tangent_Half_Angle

Comment: How did you proceed after finding out the value of dx?

Comment: @Zlatan After the substitution, you will find an integrand which is a rational function with a quadratic polynomial at the denominator. Try it!

Comment: yes but what after that to get this -->$$\int{ \frac{dx}{5\cos x-12\sin x} }=-2$$

Comment: @Zlatan factorize $5-5t^2-24t=-(5t^2+24t-5)=-(t+5)(5t-1)$

Comment: I typed that by mistake the querry was something else I've posted it the comment above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45319/discussion-between-robert-z-and-zlatan).

Comment: yes but what after that to get this -->$$\int{ \frac{dx}{5\cos x-12\sin x} }=-2$$

Comment: Don't you think this post deserves an upvote? It could be quite helpful for others who see it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$ 5 \cos x-12\sin x = 13 \sin\left(x-\arctan\frac{5}{12}\right) $$
hence it is enough to prove that
$$ \int\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta} = C+\log\tan\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

Comment: How did you get $$ 5 \cos x-12\sin x  $$ equal to $$13 \sin(x-\arctan\frac{5}{12}) $$?

Comment: @Zlatan: by the sine addition formula, $$\sin(x-\theta) = \sin(x)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\cos(x),$$ hence if you consider $\theta=\arctan\frac{5}{12}$ you have $\sin\theta=\frac{5}{13}$ and $\cos\theta=\frac{12}{13}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take $$5=r\sin(t), -12=r\cos(t)$$ where $r^2=(5)^2+(-12)^2$ and $\tan(t)=\frac{5}{-12}$.

Comment: Sorry, still got no clue how I could apply that here

Comment: what is $\sin(x+t)$? Reflect!

Comment: $sinx.cost$+$cosx.sint$? What about it?

Comment: @Zlatan Sorry if I replied you so late. Actualy yes! What I meant was exactly the Jack's answer. Sorry again. :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard trick for simplifying expressions like $A\cos t+B\sin t$.  If $r=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ you can rewrite as $r((A/r)\cos t+(B/r)\sin t).$  Then $A,B,$ and $r$ are sides of a right triangle.  If $s$ is the angle between the $B$ and $r$ sides, then $\cos s = B/r$ and $\sin s = A/r$.  Now your expression looks like $r(\sin s\cos t+\cos s\sin t) = r\cos(s+t).$  Your expression has a minus sign, so you'll have to do something to get $s$ in the right quadrant.

Comment: Great! Any more theory for me to be more familiar with it? Your help is appreciated bro.

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of integrals often boil down to what I think Spivak calls the sneakiest substitution (but also the substitution of last resort):
$$
\arctan(t)=x/2
$$
Which is what at least one of the answers is referencing. You then will have to draw a triangle to figure out what $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are.

Comment: Yes that is what I was suggesting in my question, but could you illustrate how I'd go on doing it?

Comment: which part is confusing you? Did you draw a triangle with with the opposite over adjacent side of one of the acute angles equal to $t/2$?

Comment: Shouldn't the angle be $x/2$

Comment: @Zlatan yes sorry

Comment: Cos x would be $1/(1+t^2)^{0.5}$ and sin x would be $t/(1+t^2)^{0.5}$ what after this?